# Unknown object from back of driving handle

Tags: subaru, part-identification, impreza

I found the below object lying under the driving handle of a 2015 Subaru Impreza. What is this thing? I'm pretty sure it fell off from behind the driving handle. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

-----edit-----

As per advice I was able to slot it back in.

[image]
[image]

So I guess I will change the question, why is there a screw sticking out? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It looks like a cap which goes on to studs or bolt ends.

Comment: Any identifying numbers on the underside? Doesn't ring any bells immediately.

Comment: @PeteCon It has a big "K" printed. Another 45 degrees rotation from there to the right, there is a mirror image of "2".

Comment: To hold trim or carpet?

Comment: What do you mean by "driving handle"?

Comment: @GdD the thing you hold when you drive, the round thing. But I was wrong. it's from below the acceleration pedal.

Comment: @SolarMike So you take this thing on and off affix carpets? The hole seems too deep for that.

Comment: @ztyh The "thing you hold when you drive" is the *steering wheel.*

Comment: Some cars have thicker carpets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing it in place answers the question. It's a Stopper.

https://parts.subaru.com/p/Subaru__/STOPPER-PEDAL-B/49247380/36036AA031.html

All it does it stop the accelerator pedal from going too far to the floor.